# Value of style date input not visible on mobile (iphone)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a custom icon to the html5 input `date` using a font pack. For this example I'm using FontAwesome, but in reality I'm using a custom font pack.

On mobile (I'm using an iPhone X) I can see the calendar icon, but not a value. When I change `:before` to `:after` then I can see the icon until I select a value, then I can see only the value. I suspect a shadow dom element representing the value has a set width of 100%.

```css
input[type="date"]:before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 400;
  content: "\f274";
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<input type="date" />
```

I've also tried to `position:absolute` the calendar icon (code below) which renders as I want on iPhone but looks pants on desktop browser.

```css
input[type=date] {
  position: relative;
  text-indent: 2em;
  width: 170px;
}

input[type=date]:before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 400;
  content: "\f274";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -1.25em;
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<input type="date" />
```

How can I show my calendar icon and values on `date` inputs on desktop and mobile in a consistent (I'll be happy with ~90% consistency) manner?

#### iPhone Screenshots

You can see from the code snippets what these look like on desktop, so here are screenshots of what I'm getting in Safari on iphone.

What I Want

[image: What I Want]

What I get

[image: What I get]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continued playing the `position:absolute` idea and have come up with the following "solution". It feels messy. Is there a better solution available?

```css
input[type=date] {
  position: relative;
  text-indent: 15px;
  width: 160px;
}

input[type=date]:before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 400;
  content: "\f274";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -10px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<input type="date" />
```

Comment: Working fine on IOS but not on desktop and other devices on click calender not opening